# How to achieve something like mutually binding variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Consider `b = a + 7`.

How can I have `b` keep up with `a` so that the statement remains true even as `a` changes over time?

Not only that but how can I have it also work the other way around, updating `a` accordingly in case `b` is also changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as mutually binding variables in Ruby. You can use anonymous functions (aka. lambdas) to achieve this.

```
a = 0
b = -> {a + 7}
b.()  #=> 7

a = 100
b.()  #=> 107
```

This is a bit ugly for me because `b` **implicitly** depends on `a`, which is not good in functional programming.

You can also achieve this by traditional OO if you don't mind using `obj.attr`.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a

  def b
    a + 7
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.a = 0
foo.b  #=> 7
foo.a = 100
foo.b  #=> 107
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you go about it making it work the other way around, though? Just define `b=` manually to perform the same operation from the other side?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in my experience, 2 methods changing one state is never a good idea. It leads to messy logic in the long run.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve that same result in a safe way?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find one. You should ask yourself why you need this, and whether you really need it.

Comment: Well, I'm looking into system dynamics and this is a common pattern, as tracked variables change over time and yet their relationships persist. So I wanted to play around with it in Ruby a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Proc.html) objects.

```
a = 1
b = a + 7 #=> 8

proc = Proc.new { b = a + 7  }        
 #=> #<Proc:0x0000000001038760@(irb):3>
a = 2
proc.call
b #=> 9
```

Quick overview on procs and lambas [here](https://youtu.be/VBC-G6hahWA).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with the other answer because it's more direct, but this was very helpful.